# How to create NSImage without device screen scaling

Tags: swift, image-processing, nsimage

I would like to generate 64x64 pixel NSImage and then perform pixel by pixel processing on the data.  However, when I generate the image in a fairly canonical way on my retina iMac, the resulting image is 128x128. I tried adding a custom imageRep, but that had no effect.  Here is some playground code:

```
let side = 64
let size = NSSize(width: side, height: side)
let imRect = NSRect(origin: NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: size)
let result = NSImage(size: size)
let rep2 = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
                            pixelsWide: side, pixelsHigh: side,
                            bitsPerSample: 8, samplesPerPixel: 4,
                            hasAlpha: true, isPlanar: false,
                            colorSpaceName: NSColorSpaceName.calibratedRGB,
                            bytesPerRow: side * 4, bitsPerPixel: 32)
result.addRepresentation(rep2!)
let backColor = NSColor.green
result.lockFocus()
backColor.setFill()
imRect.fill()
randomAttrGlyph.draw(at: NSPoint(x: 2, y: 2))
result.unlockFocus()
let cgImg = result.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)
```

result and cgImg are both 128x128.

Also, pulling the RGBA data produces junk, for example a .white pixel produces an
RGBA data of (0, 60, 0, 60) instead of the expected (255, 255, 255, 255)

The code I'm using for pixel data is

```
let size = image.size

let cgImg = (image.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)!)
let cgWidth = cgImg.width
let cgHeight = cgImg.height
var returnPixels = [[Pixel]](repeating: [Pixel](repeating: black, count: Int(cgWidth)), count: Int(cgHeight))  // two d array for scaled grayscale

let pixelData = (image.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)!).dataProvider!.data
let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

for y in 0..<Int(cgHeight) {
    for x in 0..<Int(cgWidth) {
        let pos = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

        let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(image.size.width) * Int(pos.y) * 4) + Int(pos.x) * 4)

        let r = data[pixelInfo]
        let g = data[pixelInfo + 1]
        let b = data[pixelInfo + 2]
        let a = data[pixelInfo + 3]
        let sum = UInt16(r) + UInt16(g) + UInt16(b)
        returnPixels[y][x] = Pixel(a: a, r: r, g: g, b: b, grey: sum) //no alpha
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Search for 'NSImage change resolutions.'

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I am indeed scaling after creation of the object as described above. I was hoping for a way to be more memory and time efficient than to make an object then modify it.